# React-Axios => Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, use-effect

I am trying to retrieve some data from an API. When I console the data it works fine:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Model() {
  
    const url = "api.blabla.com/blabla"
    const [model, setModel] = useState()
    useEffect(() => {
      const axiosPosts = async () => {
        const response = await axios(url)
        setModel(response.data)
      };
      axiosPosts();
    }, []);

   console.log(model.slug) //prints the slug!!

    
    return (
      <div>
       {model.slug} : {model.name} // TypeError slug undefined
      </div>
    )
```

What can be the problem with this code?

Comment: And where does length come into it? Note that the _initial_ state of model is indeed undefined.

Comment: Thank you for the edit and you are right problem solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes time for the api to respond, so at the start `model` is assigned the value of the parameter you passed to the `useState()` hook.

You passed nothing so during the first react render `model` is undefined.

One solution could be to change your template to:

```
{model?.slug} : {model?.name}
```

Or make it conditional

```
{model && (
  <>
    {model.slug} : {model.name}
  </>
)}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works fine right now. Is it always necessary to use data like this when fetching from API or is there any other way (possibly better practice)?

Comment: A better practice could be to create another component with only one role: render the data. You could only display this component when the data is available, just like I showed you in the second example.

Answer (score 1):

adding more to @ploppy's answer above, a common pattern here would be

```
import axios from 'axios';

export default function Model() {

const url = "api.blabla.com/blabla"
const [status, setStatus] = useState("idle");
const [model, setModel] = useState({
  slug: "",
  name: ""
})
useEffect(() => {
  setStatus("pending");
  const axiosPosts = async () => {
    try{
    const response = await axios(url)
    setModel(response.data)
    setStatus("resolved")
   }catch(error){
    console.log(error);
    setStatus("rejected");
   }
  };
  axiosPosts();
}, []);

console.log(model.slug) //prints the slug!!

if(status === "pending"){
    return (<div>Loading...</div>)
}
if(status === "rejected"){
    return (<div>Something went wrong!</div>)
}
return (
  <div>
   {model.slug} : {model.name} // TypeError slug undefined
  </div>
)
```

This gives you a good advantage to handle API calls and their responses better.